# How to test with existing ERC20 tokens on local tests

Tags: solidity, truffle, truffle-test

I have a Solidity smart contract for NFTs that I need to test using Truffle Suite. While deploying the contract on Rinkeby, I provide it with an existing ERC20 token contract address that I use for payments of the NFTs.

How do I test the NFT smart contract on my local? Do I deploy a dummy contract for the ERC20 token.

I would also like to develop a testing solution that would work in CI/CD. If I deploy the contract on my local, how do I deploy the contract using the same truffle migration files on Rinkeby or Mainnet.

On the ERC20 token, what I need my tests to do :

1. Provide the ERC20 token contract address while deploying the NFT Smart Contract
2. Approve the NFT smart contract as a spender for X tokens on a user's wallet.
3. Transfer Y tokens from one wallet to another.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'd use the same exact ERC-20 contract that is deployed in production.

Comment: You can also try to run a local fork of maiinet to have access to all the deployed contracts you can use ganache or hardhat to do so